# Use a global variable, a singleton, or something else

Tags: php, encapsulation, singleton, globals, static

**Preface:** I am working in PHP (*Abandon hope all ye who enter here*).

**Background:** There exists a large set of global functions in PHP, a number of which are miscellaneous system calls, like [sleep](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php) (and others). Now, I use `sleep` (and others) in a bunch of different scripts I run in a bunch of different places, and I have found I need sleep to call `pcntl_signal_dispatch` as soon as the `sleep` finishes- but possibly not in all my scripts.

**A Generalization:** I need to make global function do more than it currently does, hopefully without disrupting my current ecosystem too much.

**My Solution:** I figure I could create a wrapper class that executes the correct `"sleep"`.

*Singleton:* I could make a singleton "System" class that wraps the global functions. Hell, I could even make the wrappers static methods. The downside is that there would be a lot of boilerplate checking to see which version I would need to execute, either a vanilla function call or one with extra stuff.

*Global variable:* I could make a generic "System" class that wraps the global functions. I could then extend the System class with different classes that override the wrapper functions. I create a global `System` variable within each script, dependent upon how I need the functions to behave. All my scripts have access to that global variable. The downside is I would have to make sure the global variable is declared, is never overwritten, and uses the proper `System`.

*Something else:* I could create a `SysControl` class with a static `System` variable and static wrappers of the `System`'s wrappers of the functions, and then swap out which `System` my `SysControl` class references. The downside is that I feel I am going overboard.

Are there any more options I should consider? Which of these methods is the best, and why? What pitfalls should I look for going forward?

EDIT: I ended up using the *Something else* solution.

Comment: Does PHP not have first-class functions? I'm not versed enough in PHP to actually answer, but stay away from singletons, globals, or static variables. Invisible dependencies are not good. Find a way to pass in the right function to your scripts without requiring someone to mutate some global state before calling it.

Comment: @Doval The problem is, if I pass in functions as arguments, that will get very out of hand very quickly.

Comment: More quickly than using a Singleton as a switch yard?

Comment: @RobertHarvey Quite possibly, yes. If I have functions A, B, C, and D, and A calls B which calls C which calls D, and I have to pass through four functions in addition to their normal arguments, and I have this situation everywhere, that does not seem maintainable at all. Far less maintainable, in fact, than using a Singleton or global... I total agree with Doval about invisible dependencies- they have the tendency to cause headaches- but other solutions seem worse (hence the question).

Comment: Would the use of namespaces actually increase the mess, or provide another alternative ?

Comment: @mika In general, namespaces might help. In PHP, most likely they will not.

Comment: You're trying to repurpose object oriented patterns for procedural gymnastics. Abandon hope indeed. You do know that sleep() is not a guaranteed sleep, right? Sleep can spontaneously wake up if the PHP process is signaled at any point by any thing. You might want to think about refactoring the code using actual OOP patterns, IO locks, or even a different language, not just trying to shoehorn things in where they would be a convenience now, but undoubtedly contribute to the momentum of snowballing maintenance that likely prompted you to make this post in the first place.

Comment: @MirroredFate Your question is too vague. What do you mean by "ecosystem"? Do you mean spaghetti code? Are you asking us to fix your spaghetti code without seeing it. I did give you a suggestion: Refactor, use IO locks, avoid sleep.

Comment: @MirroredFate You've taken every suggestion in these comments and shot them down. Produce some code. Take a hint. There are two more suggestions for you.

Comment: I empathize, and the lesson I learned after so many similar experiences is this: don't work for people that are not good with money. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Technical_debt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Preface

For any given project, the answer to this question will likely differ. This is simply a result of structure and overall philosophy. It may be easy and straightforward in some instances, but extremely difficult and complicated in others.

*However*, if this is a difficult problem, that is a very strong code smell: something is likely quite wrong with your project. That being said, we've all been there, and we often don't have time to rewrite the entire codebase. Still, to start: what's the *right* way to solve this?

## The Right Way

[IoC (Inversion of Control)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3058/what-is-inversion-of-control) is a design pattern and principle that has steadily gained traction. It basically states that instead of objects building what they need, they request an instance of what they need from some IoC container, which can give them the appropriate "thing".

In this case, we could do something like the following:

```
interface SystemAdapterInterface
{
    public function sleep($duration);
}

class WakefulSystemAdapter implements SystemAdapterInterface
{
    public function sleep($duration)
    {
        sleep($duration);
        pcntl_signal_dispatch();
    }
}

class SleepySystemAdapter implements SystemAdapterInterface
{
    public function sleep($duration)
    {
        sleep($duration)
    }
}

class SleepingEntity
{
    public function __construct(SystemAdapterInterface $system)
    {
        $this->system = $system
    }

    public function mayReceiveSignal()
    {
        $this->system->sleep(100000);
    }
}

// Register the system and sleeping entity with the IoC Container
// Using the LoEP Container for IoC
$container = new League\Container\Container;

$container->add('SystemAdapterInterface', 'WakefulSystemAdapter ');

$container
    ->add('SleepingEntity')
    ->withArgument('SystemAdapterInterface');

//Now we can easily get an instance of sleeping entity.
$container->get('SleepingEntity');
```

In this example, we use an `IoC` container to manage what `System` `SleepingEntity` uses. My recommendation for an `IoC` is [`Container`, from the League of Extraordinary Packages](http://container.thephpleague.com/).

This solution keeps our `SleepingEntity` decoupled from our `System`. Depending on where we use `SleepingEntity`, we can simply configure our `IoC Container` differently. It's nice because it's relatively simple, easy to test, and allows for expansion in the future.

Unfortunately, this doesn't work particularly well if you already have a whole lot of code with sleeps (or similar global function calls), and you need to modify their behavior. So what can we do about that?

## The Not Quite as Right Way

Ok, so you want to do **The Right Thing**, but the code is poorly documented, has dependencies intertwined every which-way, and it is an incredibly heavy lift to go through and make sure you've passed your `IoC` every which way down the tree until it is used to instantiate the right object, every time.

The best thing to do is to be forward-looking. If you want to make the codebase better, more decoupled, take the first step with this addition.

Let's say you have the following:

```
class DoSomethingAndSleep
{
    public function foo($a, $b, $c)
    {
        $a->thing();
        $b->thing();
        sleep(5);
        $c->thing();
    }
}
```

Now let's pretend that `DoSomethingAndSleep` is used 1,000 different places by all kinds of different code. In fact, it is sometimes instantiated anonymously through an class variable, so finding those 1,000 places is hard. Really, really hard.

Fine. Let's just move the decoupling goodness into `DoSomethingAndSleep`. Hopefully you'll have time to refactor things one by one in the future.

```
class DoSomethingAndSleep
{
    public function __construct(SystemAdapterInterface $system=null)
    {
        if ($system=== null)
        {
            $system = App::getIoC()->get('SystemAdapterInterface');
        }
        $this->system = $system;
    }

    public function foo($a, $b, $c)
    {
        $a->thing();
        $b->thing();
        $this->system->sleep(5);
        $c->thing();
    }
}
```

Ok, so what's going on here? Well, there is firstly a recognition that we don't have the right infrastructure to pass the the `IoC` into `DoSomethingAndSleep`, or to use it to construct the `DoSomethingAndSleep`, so instead we're going to bypass all of that and get the "standard" `IoC` from our `App`. This means that upon application startup, we have to:

- instantiate the IoC Container
- register the SystemAdapterInterface with the IoC Container
- register the IoC Container with the App

This is acceptable. As we have a default argument in our `DoSomethingAndSleep` constructor, we can spend time moving forward refactoring things to use the `IoC Container` without breaking backwards compatibility.

We still will need to move to (hopefully) using the `Container` to manage objects and instances, but at least we're at a point where we are registering the `SystemAdapterInterface` and using the registered one instead of directly instantiating it.

If you are using the `League Container`, we can even register `DoSomethingAndSleep` with our `IoC Container` using this method, and leverage the [Auto Wiring and the Reflection Delegate](http://container.thephpleague.com/auto-wiring/) to take care of this new dependency for `DoSomethingAndSleep`.

```
$container = new League\Container\Container;

// register the reflection container as a delegate to enable auto wiring
$container->delegate(
    new League\Container\ReflectionContainer
);

$doSomethingAndSleep = $container->get('DoSomethingAndSleep');
```

This should make our future refactoring go even more smoothly.

## Conclusion

It is always difficult to figure out how to take an old, monolithic codebase and slowly make it better, more maintainable. You can't break backwards compatibility, you need to move forward with new features, and you want to make sure the additions improve things. That's tough. I think the best suggestion is this: if you can't write tests for it, you will have a terrible time maintaining it. So every time you make a change, make sure you can write a unit test against that change.

In this case, using `IoC` accomplishes this with very little effort. Even if your project isn't structured to use it, you can introduce it initially and only use it in one place, and then over time you can refactor your code until eventually everything is using [DI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) and is pleasantly decoupled.

Comment: To do it really "the right way", shouldn't SleepingEntity receive all parameters in the constructor instead of the whole IoC container?

Comment: Good point. I'll revise a bit.

Comment: When I initially wrote it I was trying to keep it "container agnostic", but that's not particularly realistic. I'll just use the League Container.

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any more options I should consider?

- have a look at php [constants](http://php.net/manual/language.constants.php) instead of global variables
- consider using bit fields instead of a `SYSTEM` variable or constant